# SSIS Incremental Load Dynamic DB

Tags: sql-server

In my SSIS project in VS 2012 I cannot use this query to dynamically select a database and use it to query a table. But the preview gets the results without issue.

```
declare @db as nvarchar(50)
declare @script varchar(max)

set @script = 'USE {DBNAME} SELECT * FROM dbo.Logs'
select @db = name from sys.databases where name like '%Perf%'
set @script = REPLACE(@script, '{DBNAME}', @db)

execute(@script)
```

Error:
HRESULT: 0xC02090F0

Comment: Can you echo your @script and see what it ultimately IS?  Your syntax for everything appears ok.  But if "name" is getting nothing back, you'd get an error.

Comment: Post the entire error message.   Run profiler while executing the package to see what command is being sent to the DB.

Comment: This query runs fine in SSMS. The issue is getting back the results for matching in my ADO NET Source.